# list out of range error - plotting from .dat file

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, text-files

I am trying to plot a .dat file using python.  However I get an error message. I'll call it 'file.dat', it's  of the following form

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
```

Using my code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open("file.dat") as f:
    data = f.read()

data = data.split('\n')

x = [row.split(' ')[0] for row in data]
y = [row.split(' ')[1] for row in data] #error from this line of code

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.set_title(" title...")    
ax1.set_xlabel('x axis')
ax1.set_ylabel('y axis')

ax1.plot(x,y, c='r', label='data')

leg = ax1.legend()

plt.show()
```

However I get an error message 'IndexError:  that the list index is out of range"  Any idea why this is?  My .dat file has the same number of elements for the x,y columns.  Thanks!

Comment: are you absolutely sure every line has two values?

Comment: use `data.splitlines()` instead of `data.split("\n")` as that will use universal newlines (it is `\n\r` on windows) and strips trailing blank lines, your problem is very likely caused by the file ending with a newline so the last entry in the list is an empty string (or `'\r'` if you are using windows), this would be fixed by using `.splitlines()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

insert

```
print data
```

Just before you find the x and y lists.  You have a newline at the end of the file, so **data** has an empty string at the end:

```
['1 2', '3 4', '5 6', '7 8', '']
```

Instead, add a slice to "massage" **data**, right after your split:

```
data = data.split('\n')[:-1]
```

This drops the last, empty, entry.

---

Per Tadhg, note that this assumes that the file ends with a newline.  If this is not guaranteed ...

```
data = data.split('\n')
if len(data[-1]) == 0:
    data.pop(-1)
```

Comment: I'm quite doubtful of this, `"".split(' ')` results in an empty list so `x` would have failed, and `" ".split(" ") -> ['', '']` so if there was only a space at the end it still wouldn't have had an `IndexError`

Comment: **''.split(' ')** returns **['']**, so the **x** extraction is okay.

Comment: so it does, my bad I was using .split` without arguments, in that case you are probably correct, however removing the last element is probably a bad idea since if the data did not end in a newline you would end up losing one set of data.